# Benalman Js does not working in Ipad. hashchange

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, ipad

I using [Benalman JS](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/docs/files/jquery-ba-hashchange-js.html)  to control the back button window redirect url to home.

I tested in normal browser and Android phone, it work accordingly.
But it does not work in Ipad,

here is a part of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
<script>
// control back button
    // includes in js mean contains 
    if(!window.location.href.includes('#state')){
        history.pushState(null ,document.title, '#state'); // forwards
    }

    // Bind an event handler.
    jQuery(window).bind('hashchange', function(e) {
        window.location = _contextPath + "/home/";
    });
</script>
 </html>
```

I notice that in Ipad the url will not append the "#state".
I suspect history.pushState not work in Ipad.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed after I change

```
includes
```

To

```
indexOf
```

Nothing to do with Benalman Js library. This js can excluded.

Thank you.